# Multiple Remote deployment of Actor in Akka without using router

Tags: akka, akka-cluster

Is there a way to deploy remote actors on more than one machine without using routers?

In the following configuration, can I put more than one address in remote??

```
akka {
  actor {
    deployment {
      /sampleActor {
        remote = "akka.tcp://sampleActorSystem@127.0.0.1:2553"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible because an [actor path](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.6/general/addressing.html) can only have one address component, either local or remote. The configuration is simply specifying the (one and only) address to use for the given actor path.

If you want messages to be forwarded to multiple actors distributed across multiple machines, then you either need to use a [router](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.6/scala/routing.html) or code this yourself by writing an actor that has the references to multiple target actors—which is essentially a custom router.

With Akka cluster this is made easier by using Cluster Aware Routers.

The links here assume Scala, but similar documentation is also available for Java.

Comment: You should consider adding a source for your answer (e.g. a link to a documentation)

Comment: Exactly why I created this as an answer instead of a comment, I don't have sufficient privileges to add a comment. In any case I will try to improve the answer.